# How to cascade @OneToOne removal?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I want to create a `@OneToOne` mapping where the root entity has a reference to a sub entity by foreign key contraint.

```
@Entity
public class MainEntity {
    @Id private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sheet_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sheet"))
    private SheetEntity sheet;
}

@Entity
public class Sheet {
    @Id private long id;
    //...

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "sheet")
    private GiataHotelEntity mainEntity;
}
```

Problem: when I go to the database and chose `truncate cascade` on the `MainEntity`, then the assiciated `@OneToOne` `Sheet` is *not* removed.

If I reverse the mapping and make `Sheet` the *owning-side*, then this cascaded delete would work! But I want the MainEntity to be the owning side.

What might I be doing wrong here?

Comment: Is there foreign key from Sheet to MainEntity in your database ?

Comment: Yes the "mainEntity" has a `fk_sheet_id` column with key of `Sheet` entity. But when I drop MainEntity, the Sheet data remains.

Comment: But Sheet has no fk_mainentity_id?

Comment: no, sheet has no foreign key!

Comment: Read my comment under answer you upvoted. Also you might find some useful in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When you run truncate `MainEntity` cascade, it is supposed to truncate the `MainEntity` table and any tables which are using `MainEntity` as foreign key    which is **NOT** the case here. In your case - the foreign key is with `MainEntity` (column **fk_sheet_id**). Had the relationship would have been created by having foreign key (referring to primary key in `MainEntity`) in `Sheet` table - your truncate script would work.

Comment: If I'm never fetching the sheet alone, but always in conjunction with the main entity - which entity would have to be the owning side? Would it be better to set the fk_mainentity_id to the sheet?

Comment: @membersound To satisfy your requirements I would declare foreign key in Sheet table and set it NOT NULL. What about hibernate, you may declare ownership on any of two sides, but if you use`@ForeignKey` it should be above real foreign key from database.

Answer (score 0):

> CASCADE Automatically truncate all tables that have foreign-key
>   references to any of the named tables, or to any tables added to the
>   group due to CASCADE.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-truncate.html

Seeing your naming like `fk_sheet_id`, I suppose there is foreign key in MainEntity to Sheet in database, but not vice versa.
So it is right that Sheet is not affected by truncate on MainEntity, because Sheet has no foreign key to MainEntity. May be you need apply `truncate cascade` on Sheet?

In the second case, when you change the owner, it seems like hibernate generates a foreign key for you in Sheet table.

> When the ConstraintMode value is CONSTRAINT, but the
>   foreignKeyDefinition element is not specified, the provider will
>   generate foreign key constraints whose update and delete actions it
>   determines most appropriate for the join column(s) to which the
>   foreign key annotation is applied.

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/ForeignKey.html

Answer (score 0):

If MainEntity is the owner of the relationship it means it depends on Sheet. If it is important for the delete on MainEntity - ran outside Hibernate - to propagate and also delete the associated Sheet, you should declare the Sheet as the owner of the relationship.

Also, JPA does not specify how and if the cascades should be delegated to the DDL.

If it is important for you to have this cascade defined at db level, you can use 
a Hibernate specific annotation: **@OnDelete**.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_sheet_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sheet"))
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private MainEntity mainEntity;
```